# Changing permissions and users that can view a directory in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions

Here is my dilemma.  We have a server with a path, say \server1\data$\foo\bar\stuff.  I'm using Windows 2005 Server for this.  Now, for \stuff, I'd like to add something like 150 users that I have in a CSV file (can get it from Excel).

I can parse the CSV file rather easily (most languages have libraries for this), but I don't know anything about Windows permissions (used Linux for quite a bit of my career prior).

Can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Derp.  Windows Server 2003 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from the command line via active directory commands through DOS or Powershell.  I list some references and examples from references below.

I would suggest adding these users to a group.  This example adds a user to a group:

```
dsmod group "CN=csvpeeps,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Contoso,DC=Com"  -addmbr "CN=jimmyCrackedCorn,CN=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=Com"
```

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732423(WS.10).aspx
To create a group, see the dsadd command.  Example of creating a group:

```
dsadd group cn=csvpeeps,cn=users,dc=northwindtraders,dc=com
```

One option on Windows, through DOS is Cacls, iCacls, and other variants.  This example adds Read permissions to a resource for the group, 'Power Users':

```
CACLS \server1\data$\foo\bar\stuff. /E /G "csvpeeps":R
```

Reference:  http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html

I have read that CACLS can be buggy, so you may want to look into another variant of CACLS.  I highly recommend http://ss64.com

If you don't know the exact OU/CN, etc for users or groups, you can check it out with something like this:

```
dsquery user -name jimmyCrackedCorn
```

Similarly for groups

```
dsquery group -name csvpeeps
```

Let me know if you get stuck and I can put more effort into this.  Powershell is another option worth looking into.

Comment: I used to work with dsmod and company on Windows Server 2003.  I never heard of 2005 Server until this convo.  If you can't get the ds* tools, I suppose you should look into Powershell.  Can you get owershell on your Windows 2005 Server?

Comment: I can use PS, but I don't know too well how to use it.  I'm a n00b at it.  Would this thread be the place to ask?

Comment: kikuchiyo, my bad, it was Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Yes, I think it is fine.  Add a 'Powershell' tag if you can.  Powershell is surprisingly similar to php in a lot of its syntax.  Now that I think about it 'Server Fault' is a nice place to post these types of questions also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my approach.  After looking at the issue.  I think PowerShell is the way to go.  I have a CSV file as mentioned above which is delimited with commas and have a the following format:

Last Name, First Name

Smith, Bob

Corn Amy

Etc.

What I'd like to do is find out the AD usernames of these people (Amy Corn will be acorn according to our internal format) and then insert them into a specific directory so that read-only directory has those users that can view its contents.  Any help is appreciated.